# OpenCV Error: Bad argument (The array of layer neuron counters must be an integer vector)

Tags: java, android, opencv, javacv

this Code is about train Neural Network using com.googlecode.javacv.cpp 
there are an error appear when i make .create method

```
static void train (CvMat TrainData, CvMat classes, int nlayers,int numOfClasses)
{
    CvANN_MLP C=new CvANN_MLP();    
    CvMat layerSizes = cvCreateMat(1, 3, CV_32FC1);
    layerSizes.put(0, 0, TrainData.cols());//put or rows or ???     
    layerSizes.put(0, 1, nlayers);      
    layerSizes.put(0, 2, numOfClasses);     
    double alpha=1.0;
    double beta=1.0;

    C.create(layerSizes, CvANN_MLP.SIGMOID_SYM, alpha,beta );//there is an error here
```

//OpenCV Error: Bad argument (The array of layer neuron counters must be an integer vector) in //CvANN_MLP::create, file ......\src\opencv\modules\ml\src\ann_mlp.cpp, line 230

```
    //Prepare trainClasses
    //Create a mat with n trained data by m classes

    CvMat trainClasses = null;
    trainClasses.create(TrainData.rows(), numOfClasses, opencv_core.CV_32FC1);
    for( int i = 0; i < trainClasses.rows(); i++ )
    {
        for( int k = 0; k < trainClasses.cols(); k++ )
        {
            int [] ClassesNumber =new int[1];
            //If class of data i is same than a k class
           classes.get(i, k );

            if(k ==  ClassesNumber[0])
            {
                trainClasses.put(i, k);
            }

            else{
                trainClasses.put(i, k);

            }

        }
    }

    CvMat weights = cvCreateMat( 1, TrainData.rows(), opencv_core.CV_32FC1 );
    cvSet(weights, CvScalar.ONE);

    //Scler 1111111111
    //Learn classifier
     C.train(TrainData, trainClasses, weights,null,new CvANN_MLP_TrainParams(), 0);
```

//       trained=true;

```
}
```

Comment: @PeterSmith i call the method in this way                       train (TrainFromFileMatrix,ClassesMatrix,1,numOfClasses);

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to find the exact problem, but the error is because you're trying to put a non-integer number of neurons into a layer. Neural networks work with a discrete number of neurons in each layer. Perhaps you've assigned 0 neurons or a negative number of neurons by accident? Make sure that your parameters are being placed in the correct order when calling methods or constructors.

You're telling the train method that you have 0 classes to output.
Thus you're trying to put 0 neurons in a layer. You need to decide how many outputs you are expecting and it has to be greater than zero.

```
if(x>0)
    C.train(TrainData, trainClasses, weights,null,new CvANN_MLP_TrainParams(), x);
else
    //it won't work
```

Also, why are you passing 6 arguments to a method with 4 parameters?... You must not be showing on of your methods - or you really have no idea what this code is doing. In which case you shouldn't be using it.. Use it like the following:

```
layerSizes.put(0, 0, #inputs);     
layerSizes.put(0, 1, #hidden neurons);      
layerSizes.put(0, 2, #outputs);
```

Comment: @PeterSmith i path the number of neurons =1 ;

Comment: @PeterSmith  i made a method that train my data that is all

Comment: I see that, but you do not appear to know how to use it. Do you know what a multilayer perceptron is? You're not passing valid arguments.

Comment: Read through this and I bet you will have a better idea of how to use that library.http://ml.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/_media/teaching/ss10/05_mlps.printer.pdf

Comment: @PeterSmith could you send me your mail ?

Comment: No, sorry. Just take some time to read up on what a MLP actually is. IT requires a number of inputs, a number of hidden layers (and a number of hidden neurons within each layer), and a number of outputs. You're currently not providing a valid number for those things. And the code you've currently listed won't even compile - so you must be missing something from your post. If you could accept the answer and read up on MLP and the OpenCV library I'm sure it will begin to make sense eventually.

Comment: I know that. The problem though - relates to the properties you are setting in the layerSizes variable. Please accept my answer and then educate yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but for anyone that finds this while searching (as I just did). The error in the first block of code.

//OpenCV Error: Bad argument (The array of layer neuron counters must be an integer vector) in //CvANN_MLP::create, file ......\src\opencv\modules\ml\src\ann_mlp.cpp, line 230

is due to the type of matrix used  CV_32FC1 is not an integer type so even if you put integer values in it you will produce that error.  Try  CV_32SC1 or any type for which CvType.isInteger(type) returns 1.